# PhoneStateListener acting weird?

Tags: android

The weird thing that's happening is  when i listen all the three states

1. LISTEN_CELL_INFO
2. LISTEN_CELL_LOCATION
3. LISTEN_SIGNAL_STRENGTHS

`oncellInfoChanged()` and `onCellLocationChanged()` gets called only once at the time of registeration and i receive regular updates of `onSignalStrengthsChanged()` only. However if i comment `LISTEN_SIGNAL_STRENGTHS` the other two starts getting updates properly. Can anyone point out the issue in this?

```
public class GSMCellInfoListener {

        TelephonyManager teleManager = null;
        Context mContext;
        GSMCellInfoProvider mGsmCellInfoProvider;

        public GSMCellInfoListener(Context ctx) {
            mContext = ctx;
            mGsmCellInfoProvider = new GSMCellInfoProvider();
        }

        public void addListener() {
            teleManager = (TelephonyManager) mContext
                    .getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
            teleManager.listen(mGsmCellInfoProvider,
                    PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CELL_INFO);
            teleManager.listen(mGsmCellInfoProvider,
                    PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CELL_LOCATION);
            teleManager.listen(mGsmCellInfoProvider,
                    PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_SIGNAL_STRENGTHS);
        }

        public void removeListener() {
            teleManager
                    .listen(mGsmCellInfoProvider, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_NONE);
        }

        public void deleteListener() {
            teleManager = null;
            mGsmCellInfoProvider = null;
        }

        class GSMCellInfoProvider extends PhoneStateListener {
            @Override
            public void onCellInfoChanged(List<CellInfo> cellInfo) {
                super.onCellInfoChanged(cellInfo);
            }

            @Override
            public void onSignalStrengthsChanged(SignalStrength signalStrength) {
                super.onSignalStrengthsChanged(signalStrength);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCellLocationChanged(CellLocation location) {
                super.onCellLocationChanged(location);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried registering to all 3 events at once with only 1 listener? Internally the mGsmCellInfoProvider may be in a Map or Set, so duplicates aren't allowed, causing the later .listen(...) call to override earlier ones.

Try this:

```
public void addListener() {
        teleManager = (TelephonyManager) mContext
                .getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        int listenMask = PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CELL_INFO +
                         PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CELL_LOCATION +
                         PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_SIGNAL_STRENGTHS;
        teleManager.listen(mGsmCellInfoProvider,listenMask);
    }
```